# Duplicate identifier fetch in typescript

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

Just starting out with Typescript. Made a simple project with a single index.ts file which i want to utilize `node-fetch`. So my code looks like

#### index.ts

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch("https://www.google.com")
```

When running `tsc index.ts` i get the following

`../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17778:18 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'fetch'.`

#### My understanding

Looks like the typescript module installed globally includes types for fetch. I have two questions with regards to this

#### Questions

- a) How can I make it so that `tsc` only looks at my current directory downards for types?
- b) If i do nothing, what directories is `tsc` looking in in order to determines types?
- c) Any obvious flaws to my approach a) worth mentioning?

EDIT: 
I've also added https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node-fetch in hope it will take precedence but no joy

Comment: I think the section [@types, typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) might have the answer for your questions **but** 
_fetch_ is defined in the lib.dom.d.ts and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) says that if _lib_ is not defined the in the tsconfig,some default libs(DOM included) will be injected. I think in this case just defining "lib": [...] with the libs you are using not including the "dom" would solve the issue...

Comment: What is the content of your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Paleo its just the basic tsc --init config, not much really. - as we speak im looking into joseph-climber's response, which seems to make sense -

Comment: @joseph-climber unfortunately setting "lib": ["ESNext.Symbol"] completely ignoring mostly everything still yields the same issue.

Comment: Do you want to execute your code on Node.js or in a browser?

Comment: node, hence node-fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install typings for Node.js and `node-fetch`:

```
npm install -D @types/node@10 @types/node-fetch
```

Then, use `node-fetch`:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
fetch("https://www.google.com");
```

Notice the presence of the keyword `import`. An `import` or an `export` indicates to the compiler that your file is a ES6 module and not a script. In a module, you can define variables as you want without override global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Either list the file or include externally  : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/files.html

Comment: I attempted this but as suspected it unfortunately doesnt work. It seems like typescript is by definition looking at ```../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts```. I did try to "exclude": ["../../../../.nvm/**/*"] but it seems odd that i'd have to do this.. joseph-climber's answer made some sense but im still feeling like im missing something. My project is completely new, there's no other modules in it than ```node-fetch``` either

Comment: have you installed typescript globally? if not try to install globally and try